# Remote Powershell Access denied for certain dll's execution for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, remote-server, powershell-remoting

I am attempting to automate a sharepoint 2013 deployment via remote powershell from the build server. Everything executes as expected except when having anything to do with some class in sharepoint dll's such as (Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings)

If I run the same script locally under the same credentials it runs fine.

I have considered the below:

1. The user has full admin right on both machines
2. Disabled UAC on the remote server
3. Followed the required Remote Powershell steps in thig post (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/09b60466-5432-48c9-aedd-1af343e957de/user-cannot-be-found-when-using-invokecommand-newspsite-on-sharepoint)
4. I set powershell to run as admin by defualt via the registry (`New-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowershellScript.1\Shell\runas\command" -Force -Name '' -Value '"c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit "%1"'`)

Script Code:

```
  #Set the radio buttons value
    $settings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings (,$rootWeb)
    $settings.GlobalNavigation.Source = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource]::PortalProvider
    #Set the radio buttons value
    $settings.CurrentNavigation.Source = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource]::PortalProvider

    write-host "I am here.........................."

    $settings.Update()

    #Set the Publishing Web
    $SPPubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($rootWeb)

    #Global Navigation Settings
    $SPPubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = $false
    $SPPubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = $false
```

The Remote Powershell output is as below:

```
I am here..........................
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
    + PSComputerName        : Contoso-DEVSP

Exception setting "GlobalIncludePages": "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
    + PSComputerName        : Contoso-DEVSP
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Actually a quick update, it seems like its Sharepoint that is rejecting access to its site when publish the site. So my finding now point me to Sharepoint being paranoid not dll Trust level.

Comment: Forgot to add that the user performing publishing is a sharepoint Farm admin and an administrator on the site. When the publishing happens locally I guess authentication happens with sharepoint, but when the script runs via Remote-Powershell Access denied exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check CredSSP authentication. Remote PowerShell execution with SharePoint fails as the second hop translates the credentials to system credentials. If the task involves querying or updating DB server, it will fail as SYSTEM account will not have access the remote PowerShell on SQL Server. You need to enable CredSSP.

Check this blog post I wrote a while ago. This is not specific to SharePoint but it should apply to your scenario as well.

http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I forgot to mention that the script has other steps such as deleting site, recreating site, importing wsp's. They all work fine, except the publishing for sharepoint step. What I know it uses http, so probably the authentication is lost somewhere there. I came across this blog [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7d5dfa83-71ba-4dd4-8a3f-543b64ba0a55/powershell-remoting-access-denied-with-sharepoint-commands) which had a similar issue to mine.

TryingFiguring out how to run 'winrm OPERATION' as thats the only thing I haven't executd